# Calculate Date from the Difference in Weeks

Tags: sql, date

Example today's @date = 2010-02-22 14:17:19.393 
        Number @weeks = 2 
Equation I am looking for is (@date - @weeks = 2010-02-08 14:17:19.393)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What type of database are you using (so we can give you a useful answer)?

Answer (score 1):

```
select dateadd(week, @weeks*-1, @date)
```