# How do I find out what the date some weeks ago was?

Tags: perl, date

I was trying to determine a good way to calculate a previous date based on how many weeks I would want to go back. Today is 7/19/2011, so if I wanted to go back 5 weeks what would be the best way to determine what that date would be?

Comment: For linky goodness: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311385/calculate-date-from-the-difference-in-weeks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DateTime::Duration` is your friend there:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use DateTime;

my $now = DateTime->now(time_zone => 'local');
my $five_weeks = DateTime::Duration->new(weeks => 5);
my $five_weeks_ago = $now - $five_weeks;

say "Five weeks ago now it was $five_weeks_ago";
```

Notice that it lets you specify the duration in the units of the problem.

Comment: `->now` is in GMT which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: However, `->from_epoch` is exactly what I don't want.

Answer (score 3):

Perl has this marvelous thing called regexes that can solve almost any problem.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $date = shift || '7/19/2011';
my $days_ago = shift || 7*5;

$date =~ s#^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)\z#@{[sprintf"%.2d",$1]}/@{[sprintf"%.2d",$2]}/$3/$days_ago#;
until ( $date =~ s#^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/0\z#@{[$1+0]}/@{[$2+0]}/$3# ) {
    $date =~ s#([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)#@{[$2==1?sprintf"%.2d",$1-1||12:$1]}/@{[sprintf"%.2d",$2-1||31]}/@{[$1==1 && $2==1?$3-1:$3]}/@{[$4-1]}#;
    $date =~ s#([0-9]+)\z#@{[$1+1]}# unless $date =~ m#^(?:0[1-9]|1[012])/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]|(?<!0[2469]/|11/)31|(?<!02/)30|(?<!02/(?=...(?:..(?:[02468][1235679]|[13579][01345789])|(?:[02468][1235679]|[13579][01345789])00)))29)/#;
}
print $date, "\n";
```

(Please don't do it this way.)

Comment: I dunno, 5 regexes and a loop, might be slow... Better to combine that into a single regex with embedded code blocks, while coding the loop into the backtracking :)

Comment: The last two regexes could be combined into a single substitution, but I was too lazy.

Comment: I wish it to be noted that my upvote in no way should be construed as condoning this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Best or easiest?  I have always found [`strftime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html#strftime)'s date normalization to be handy for this sort of thing:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX qw/strftime/;

my @date = localtime;

print strftime "today is %Y-%m-%d\n", @date;

$date[3] -= 5 * 7;

print strftime "five weeks ago was %Y-%m-%d\n", @date;
```

Which solution is best depends partly on what you want to do with the date when you are done.  Here is a benchmark with implementations of various methods:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Benchmark;

use Date::Manip qw/UnixDate/;
use Date::Simple qw/today/;
use Date::Calc qw/Add_Delta_Days Today/;
use DateTime;
use POSIX qw/strftime/;
use Class::Date;

my %subs = (
    cd => sub {
        (Class::Date::now - [0, 0, 5 * 7])->strftime("%Y-%m-%d");
    },
    dc => sub {
        sprintf "%d-%02s-%02d", Add_Delta_Days Today, -5 * 7;
    },
    dm => sub {
        UnixDate("5 weeks ago", "%Y-%m-%d");
    },
    ds => sub {
        (today() - 5 * 7)->strftime("%Y-%m-%d");
    },
    dt => sub {
        my $now = DateTime->from_epoch(epoch => time, time_zone => "local");
        my $five_weeks = DateTime::Duration->new(weeks => 5);
        ($now - $five_weeks)->ymd('-');
    },
    p => sub {
        my @date = localtime;
        $date[3] -= 5 * 7;
        strftime "%Y-%m-%d", @date;
    },
    y => sub {
        my ($d, $m, $y) = (localtime)[3..5];
        my $date = join "/", $m+1, $d, $y+1900;
        my $days_ago = 7*5;

        $date =~ s#^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)\z#@{[sprintf"%.2d",$1]}/@{[sprintf"%.2d",$2]}/$3/$days_ago#;
        until ( $date =~ s#^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/0\z#@{[$1+0]}/@{[$2+0]}/$3# ) {
            $date =~ s#([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)#@{[$2==1?sprintf"%.2d",$1-1||12:$1]}/@{[sprintf"%.2d",$2-1||31]}/@{[$1==1 && $2==1?$3-1:$3]}/@{[$4-1]}#;
            $date =~ s#([0-9]+)\z#@{[$1+1]}# unless $date =~ m#^(?:0[1-9]|1[012])/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]|(?<!0[2469]/|11/)31|(?<!02/)30|(?<!02/(?=...(?:..(?:[02468][1235679]|[13579][01345789])|(?:[02468][1235679]|[13579][01345789])00)))29)/#;
        }
        return $date;
    },
);

print "$_: ", $subs{$_}(), "\n" for keys %subs;

Benchmark::cmpthese -1, \%subs;
```

And here are the results.  The `strftime` method seems to be the fastest, but it is also has the least features.

```
y: 6/14/2011
dm: 2011-06-14
p: 2011-06-14
dc: 2011-06-14
cd: 2011-06-14
dt: 2011-06-15
ds: 2011-06-14
      Rate    dt    dm     y    ds    cd    dc     p
dt  1345/s    --   -5%  -28%  -77%  -82%  -96%  -98%
dm  1408/s    5%    --  -24%  -75%  -81%  -96%  -98%
y   1862/s   38%   32%    --  -68%  -75%  -95%  -97%
ds  5743/s  327%  308%  208%    --  -24%  -84%  -90%
cd  7529/s  460%  435%  304%   31%    --  -78%  -87%
dc 34909/s 2495% 2378% 1775%  508%  364%    --  -39%
p  56775/s 4121% 3931% 2949%  889%  654%   63%    --
```

Better than a benchmark is a test of how they handle [DST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) (this test would have caught the error in the assumption about what `DateTime->now` returns).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Mock;
use Date::Manip qw/UnixDate/;
use Date::Simple qw/today/;
use Date::Calc qw/Add_Delta_Days Today/;
use DateTime;
use POSIX qw/strftime mktime/;
use Class::Date;

sub target {
        my @date = localtime;
        $date[3] -= 5 * 7;
        strftime "%Y-%m-%d", @date;
}

my %subs = (
    cd => sub {
        (Class::Date::now - [0, 0, 5 * 7])->strftime("%Y-%m-%d");
    },
    dc => sub { sprintf "%d-%02s-%02d", Add_Delta_Days Today, -5 * 7;
    },
    dm => sub {
        UnixDate("5 weeks ago", "%Y-%m-%d");
    },
    ds => sub {
        (today() - 5 * 7)->strftime("%Y-%m-%d");
    },
    dt => sub {
        my $now = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => time, time_zone => 'local' );
        my $five_weeks = DateTime::Duration->new(weeks => 5);
        ($now - $five_weeks)->ymd('-');
    },
    y => sub {
        my ($d, $m, $y) = (localtime)[3..5];
        my $date = join "/", $m+1, $d, $y+1900;
        my $days_ago = 7*5;

        $date =~ s#^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)\z#@{[sprintf"%.2d",$1]}/@{[sprintf"%.2d",$2]}/$3/$days_ago#;
        until ( $date =~ s#^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/0\z#@{[$1+0]}/@{[$2+0]}/$3# ) {
            $date =~ s#([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)#@{[$2==1?sprintf"%.2d",$1-1||12:$1]}/@{[sprintf"%.2d",$2-1||31]}/@{[$1==1 && $2==1?$3-1:$3]}/@{[$4-1]}#;
            $date =~ s#([0-9]+)\z#@{[$1+1]}# unless $date =~ m#^(?:0[1-9]|1[012])/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]|(?<!0[2469]/|11/)31|(?<!02/)30|(?<!02/(?=...(?:..(?:[02468][1235679]|[13579][01345789])|(?:[02468][1235679]|[13579][01345789])00)))29)/#;
        }
        return join "-", map { sprintf "%02d", $_ } 
            (split "/", $date)[2,0,1];
    },
);

my $time = mktime 0, 0, 0, 13, 2, 111; #2011-03-13 00:00:00, DST in US

for my $offset (map { $_ * 60 * 60 } 1 .. 24) {
    print strftime "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\n", (localtime $time + $offset);
    Time::Mock->set($time + $offset);
    my $target = target;

    for my $sub (sort keys %subs) {
        my $result = $subs{$sub}();
        if ($result ne $target) {
            print "$sub disagrees: ",
                "time $time target $target result $result\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lol... we're going to compare date calculations based on benchmark results? :)  We could cache the results too.  That way the calculation won't have to be done more than once a day unless the number of weeks back changes. (It's ok, I found it interesting.)  It's surprising to see how well dc did.

Comment: DC has never been a slouch.  To be fair, it should also say "the dt method seems to be the slowest, but it also had the most features".  (DT isn't inherently slow; a lot of what kills it, at least in cases I've looked closely at, is Params::Validate, something none of the others do.)

Comment: @DavidO The benchmark was partly out of curiosity and partly because it provided a good excuse to have lots of examples.

Comment: @ysth It looks like your solution beats `DateTime` and `Date::Manip`.

Comment: @Chas. Owens: It's ok, I was teasing.  A fun diversion.

Comment: Why does the DateTime version have a different answer?

Comment: @Justin Hawkins Good catch, that is what I get for using someone else's code without checking it first.  From the docs: "By default, the returned object will be in the UTC time zone."  This is why you should always read the docs.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Date::Calc](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Date%3a%3aCalc)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Date::Calc qw/Add_Delta_Days Today/;

my $offset_weeks = -5;
my $offset_days = $offset_weeks * 7;

# Year, Month, Day
my @delta_date = Add_Delta_Days( 
    Today( [ localtime ] ), 
    $offset_days 
);

printf "%2d/%2d/%4d\n", @delta_date[1,2,0];
```

It is designed to catch common gotchas such as leap year.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time%3a%3aPiece):

```
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds qw(ONE_DAY);

my $weeks_back = 5;
my $date_str = '7/19/2011';
my $dt = Time::Piece->strptime($date_str, '%m/%d/%Y');

# Avoid DST issues
$dt -= ONE_DAY() * ( 7 * $weeks_back - 0.5 )
my $past_str = $dt->strftime('%m/%d/%Y');
print "$past_str\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Too much code for such a simple question! All you need is two simple lines:

```
my $five_weeks_ago = time - (5*7)*24*60*60;
print scalar localtime($five_weeks_ago), "\n";
```

My solution is accurate for both DST and leap years.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to get the date of 5 weeks back:

```
$ uname
HP-UX
$ date
Wed Nov 11 09:42:05 CST 2015
$ perl -e 'my ($d,$m,$y) = (localtime(time-60*60*24*(5*7)))[3,4,5]; printf("%d/%d/%d\n", $m+1, $d, $y+1900);'
10/7/2015
```

Answer (score -1):

```
say POSIX::strftime( 
      '%m/%d/%Y'     # format string -> mm/dd/YYYY
    , 0              # no seconds
    , 0              # no minutes
    , 0              # no hours
    , 19 - ( 5 * 7 ) # current day - numweeks * 7
    , 7 - 1          # month - 1
    , 2011 - 1900    # YYYY year - 1900
    );
```

*Yes*, the day comes out to be `19 - 35 = -16`, and *yes* it works.

Comment: `strftime` normalizes for you (that is why it is slower than `sprintf` at formatting the date), so you can just subtract `5 * 7` days from the day field and it will do the right thing.

Answer (score -2):

If date is available as unix timestamp, it can be done with simple arithmetic:

```
use POSIX qw/strftime/;
say strftime('%Y-%m-%d', localtime(time - 5 * 7 * 86400));
```

Comment: This will fail on DTS switch days, because there is less (or more) then 86400 seconds in a day.

Comment: easily fixed by using gmtime, not localtime

Comment: @ysth More easily fixed by letting `strftime` normalize the date for you.